# $event not defined in ng-change on text input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope my issue is simple to solve, I can't access the value by `ng-model` because i have multiple of these boxes as they are rendered as part of a list of inputs in a form. I am trying to get the ID and text value of a text box with `ng-change`. heres my html:

```
<input type="text" class="other-box" ng-model="test" id="4" ng-change="otherBoxUpdate(this)"/>
```

(ng-model is required, which is why it's in there). Hers is my controller snippet:

```
$scope.otherBoxUpdate = function (obj, $event) {

    console.log(obj)
    console.log($event)
    console.log($event.target)
}
```

`obj` seems to return a scope value, however from what i've read I need to access `$event.target`, however `$event` is not defined. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to access the $event? Can you explicitly pass some other identifying information to your handler? Like the id for that input? `ng-change="otherBoxUpdate(4)"`

Comment: @CalvinBelden oh my god that worked you're my hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to identify the input that was clicked, you can pass some other piece of identifying information to your handler. For example, we can pass the id:

```
<input type="text" class="other-box" ng-model="test" id="4" ng-change="otherBoxUpdate(4)"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

ng-change not allow to pass $event as parameter.

```
 ng-change="otherBoxUpdate(test)"
```

```js
var myapp = angular.module('app', []);
myapp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.otherBoxUpdate = function (obj) {

    console.log(obj);
}
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">

<input type="text" class="other-box" ng-model="test" id="4" ng-change="otherBoxUpdate(4)"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: using the same `function(obj, $event)` turns obj into the value of the textbox but thats it, just the value of whats typed in. and `$event` is null, is there no way to access the `id` through this?